# How to determine when PTY.spawn has finished in ruby script so then to start new process

Tags: ruby, bash, process, expect, pty

I have a Ruby script that spawns a process and uses expect to wait for a request for input, provide that input and then when the process is finished, to spawn a new process.

Initially the problem was that the script didn't wait for the first process to finish, and executed the next line in the script.

So I added Process.wait(pid) to the script, but now the script hangs waiting for input on the second `PTY.spawn` at `Process.wait(pid)`.

I'm running the script with Ruby 1.9.2, as I know there were [some problems with `PTY.spawn`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874604/how-do-i-get-the-pty-spawn-child-exit-code) in Ruby 1.8.7.

The script looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'pty'
require 'expect'


  PTY.spawn(" apt-get install policycoreutils ") do |reader, writer, pid|
    puts reader.expect(/Do you want to continue/)
    writer.printf("Y\n")
    Process.wait(pid)
  end

  PTY.spawn(" apt-get install libmagick9-dev ") do |reader, writer, pid|
    puts reader.expect(/Do you want to continue/)
    writer.printf("Y\n")
    Process.wait(pid)
  end
```

Does anyone know why the script hangs at `Process.wait(pid)` for the second `PTY.spawn`?

Comment: Just a guess, but could the second `apt-get` be colliding with the first one? Seems to me it won't let you do two concurrently.

Comment: I think the Process.wait(pid) for the first apt-get waits until the first apt-get finishes, before existing the do-end section of the first PTY.spawn.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To help you debug, I reduced the code a bit, and spawned a more benign command:

```
require 'pty'
require 'expect'

PTY.spawn("sleep 1;echo 1") do |reader, writer, pid|
  puts reader.expect(/1/)
  Process.wait(pid)
end

PTY.spawn("sleep 1;echo 2") do |reader, writer, pid|
  puts reader.expect(/2/)
  Process.wait(pid)
end
```

This outputs:

```
ruby test.rb 
1
2
```

This implies to me that the problem lies in the `apt-get` commands.

Comment: the Tin Man - Well you definitely pointed me in the right direction, as you can see in my answer below.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Actually I found a solution and it was very simple but a little surprising.  What the second apt-get really asks is

```
 "Do you want to continue [Y/n]? "
```

I think what was happening was that the expect was matching on the first part of this string and sending the "Y" before the string had finished being fully output and the apt-get wasn't ready to receive the "Y".  Once I changed the expect match to the string above, as in the code below, then it all worked fine.

```
PTY.spawn(" apt-get install libmagick9-dev ") do |reader, writer, pid|
   puts reader.expect(/Do you want to continue \[Y\/n\]\? /)
   writer.printf("Y\n")
   Process.wait(pid)
 end
```

Comment: Try `Regexp.escape('Do you want to continue [Y/n]?')` which results in
`Do\ you\ want\ to\ continue\ \[Y/n\]\?`. You could probably just match on `Regexp.escape('[Y/n]?')` which generates `\[Y/n\]\?` I tend to use `Regexp.escape` when my pattern would result in a lot of line-noise from escaping. It's a coding preference related to maintenance.